# Check if there is 24 hours gone since a Woocommerce order is made

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, orders

I call a Woocommerce method `$order->get_date_created()` that is returning this `WC_DateTime` object:

```
object(WC_DateTime)#26619 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]=> int(0) ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-09-06 14:28:17.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam" }
```

How can I check if there is more (or less) than 24 hours are gone since the order is made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to check if there is more (or less) than 24 hours passed since an order has been created, using `WC_DateTime` and `DateTime` methods on Order created date time:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id); // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object

$date_created_dt = $order->get_date_created(); // Get order date created WC_DateTime Object
$timezone        = $date_created_dt->getTimezone(); // Get the timezone
$date_created_ts = $date_created_dt->getTimestamp(); // Get the timestamp in seconds

$now_dt = new WC_DateTime(); // Get current WC_DateTime object instance
$now_dt->setTimezone( $timezone ); // Set the same time zone
$now_ts = $now_dt->getTimestamp(); // Get the current timestamp in seconds

$twenty_four_hours = 24 * 60 * 60; // 24hours in seconds

$diff_in_seconds = $now_ts - $date_created_ts; // Get the difference (in seconds)

// Output
if ( $diff_in_seconds < $twenty_four_hours ) {
    echo '<p>Order created LESS than 24 hours ago</p>';
} elseif ( $diff_in_seconds = $twenty_four_hours ) {
    echo '<p>Order created 24 hours ago</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Order created MORE than 24 hours ago</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an order was created more than 24 hours ago, you can subtract the current timestamp from the order timestamp and then check if that difference is greater than DAY_IN_SECONDS.

```
time() - $order->get_date_created()->getTimestamp() > DAY_IN_SECONDS
```